# Obtain residuals using results post modelling

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, residuals, asreml

I trained many (LMM) models (ASReml-R), and wrote over the residual plots I was saving out. This is a univariate model with two explanatory variables, one is binary, the other 0-100. Many dependent variables I was looping over.

I have coefficients of the binary level of interest (a lethal recessive for clarity), SD, DOF. Rather than retraining the models, is there any way I could obtain the residuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to obtain the actual residuals is by re-fitting the models.